# How to run a long query from a trigger without upset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have some log records that are inserted into a table in my database. When they land, I would like to process them asap. The processing could potentially be a bit lengthy.

I would just write a trigger to do the processing, but I'm worried it will cause problems if it takes a while.

Is there a way to call a stored procedure asynchronously from a trigger? Or perhaps a better way of doing this altogether?

Comment: Can't you schedule the SP the run every 10 mins and only process new rows?

Comment: Maybe you should look at optimizing the processing, which can be useful whether you use some async method or not. Sure, performance is *less* important when someone isn't waiting, but it's still important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to use "SQL Server Service Broker". It allow you to run queries asynchronously not only in triggers.

Here is the link to documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx

Here is a link to a tutorial that works through how to set this up: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Service+Broker/73398/

Comment: I suggest you improve your answer with a simple SB queue activated proc example and trigger code.

Comment: This turned out to be exactly what I was looking for. Here is a link to a tutorial I found extremely useful in working it through. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Service+Broker/73398/